# google maps for rails location floating on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

- Rails 4.0.1
- geocoder 1.1.9
- gmaps4rails 2.1.1

Anyone got such strange issue for this gem? I make everything in video tutorial. I need GMaps to show concrete address of place, but it's showing something "near" and always randomize location about 500 meters(as i saw)

That's how it looks in google maps:
[image]

That how it looks in my app:
[image]

And after Ctrl+r it looks very different:
[image]

Maybe i made something wrong or you have the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a feature to prevent overlapping. [Its documented in the code here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/objects/handler.coffee#L5).

You can customise or remove the behaviour, example:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
```

Comment: thanks a lot @apneadiving . it worked and everything is great now :)

Comment: And IMO it should be null by default.

Comment: @NimaIzadi feel free to edit the wiki. The default value is debatable but yeah, I kept this historic setting which is useful when you've got people only entering their city's name. BTW +1 are always welcome when it helps :)

Comment: @NimaIzadi its now the default in 2.1.2, community has been heard :_